# HDMI splitter fails when pluging in the secound output

Tags: display, hdmi, splitter

I'm trying to use an HDMI splitter to connect my computer (input) to a monitor and a beamer (output 1 and output 2, respectively).

When plugging the input and output 1 to the splitter, things are working just fine, but as soon as I plug in output 2 my output 1 loses signal (even when my output 2 is turned off)

Any idea what might cause this problem ?

Here's the splitter used:
https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B019RMY462/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Can you give more information as to what the specific pieces of hardware are? it sounds like either a defect with the specific splitter or the devices themselves.

Comment: I'm not sure HDMI is really designed to be split. You'd have to really know what you're doing w.r.t. EDID and HDCP. I think your graphics card is probably getting confused by having two different devices send EDID info to it.

Comment: @MattVoboril edited the question to show the splitter used ( I know it's cheap stuff don't misjudge me :3 )

Comment: @Spiff I'd accept this explanation if the second device I plugged in was turned on. The thing is that even when the second device is turned off, plugin it in while cause the first one to not detect signal anymore

Comment: Since HDMI isn't designed to be split, you probably ruined the signal integrity of the path to output 1 when you plugged in the cable for output 2. Stub wiring can cause signal reflection and pick up noise. There's no such thing as an HDMI-certified splitter because HDMI is not designed to be split.

Comment: I'm going with @Spiff on this